# Big json data does not return fastly from TOAST?

Tags: postgresql, toast

I have trouble with my table that has four columns which their data types are text, JSON, boolean and timestamp.
I have a table like;

```
CREATE TABLE zamazin
(
  paramuser_id text,
  paramperson_id integer,
  paramdata json,
  paramisdeleted boolean,
  paramactiontime timestamp without time zone
)
```

paramdata row size is 110KB and over.

When I execute this query like;

```
select * from zamazin
```

it takes 600 seconds.
But when analyze the query ;

```
"Seq Scan on public.zamazin  (cost=0.00..21.77 rows=1077 width=49) (actual time=0.008..0.151 rows=1077 loops=1)"
"  Output: paramuser_id, paramperson_id, paramdata, paramisdeleted, paramactiontime"
"  Buffers: shared hit=11"
"Planning time: 0.032 ms"
"Execution time: 0.236 ms"
```

Why the query takes a long time, I do not understand. I assume that this relates to the TOAST structure.
Also I have 1K rows, but my json column size approximately 110KB and maybe over it.

When I investigated why these execution times are so different, I find a new storage logic like TOAST.
I overlook some details on TOAST logic and increased some config like shared_buffers, work_mem, maintenance_work_mem, max_file_per_process.

But there was no performance improvement on my query.

I do not understand why it happens. My table size is 168 MB, but my TOAST table size that is related to that table is 123 MB.

My environment is;

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.1
Windows Server 2012 R2 
16 GB RAM
100 GB HardDisk (Not SSD) – I also test SSD hard disk but there is no change in my execution time.
My database size 20 GB.
```

My server configuration ;

```
Shared_buffers: 8GB 

( If I understand correctly, PostgreSQL say, For 9.4 The useful range for shared_buffers on Windows systems is generally from 64MB to 512MB. Link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/runtime-config-resource.html )

work_mem : 512 MB
maintenance_work_mem: 1GB
max_file_per_process: 10000
effective_cache_size: 8GB
```

I tested many clients such as psql, pgadmin3, pgadmin4 and dbeaver however my execution time did not increase.

How I can achieve good performance?

My front side code is like;

```
/* it is a pseudocode*/
    public static List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            User user;
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            string errMsg = string.Empty;
            string sql = string.Empty;

            sql = @"select * from zamazin  order by paramuser_id asc;";


            }
            try
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();

                DataTable dt = DBHelper.DataTable(sql, null);
                sw.Stop();
                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1500) 
                    Debug.WriteLine("Finished " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
                if (dt == null)
                    throw new Exception();
                sw.Restart();
                foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Convert.ToString(rows["data"]),
                                            DL_General.Jsonsettings);
                        if (user != null)
                        {


                            users.Add(user);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ///bla bla
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1500) 
                       Console.WriteLine(End loop " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + ");

                return users;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //bla bla
            }
            return new List<User>();

        }
```

Comment: Is your database local? Or is it on a remote network? If it's on a network, `select * from zamazin` will include the time needed to send the 100+MB. Also, Postgres 9.4 hits end of life on Feb 13th. I would suggest trying an upgraded Postgres and switching to the more efficient `jsonb` data type.

Comment: Yes, it is my local database. I also tested the PG11 version, also test `jsonb` data type, but there is no change. When I select the data without `json` column, the execution time had been 95 ms. Also when I copy all data to CSV, the process has been very fast but I don't do that. After deserializing the `json` on front side, I want to visualize my data on the web page effectively.

Comment: If it's fast when you dump the output to CSV, then it's not the server or the network; it just takes a long time for a client to display this much data. TOAST tables are compressed, so the actual data displayed by the client will be much more than 123MB.

Comment: You query runs in  0.236 **milli** seconds. If you see any slowness, it's definitely not on the server side.

Comment: *What exactly* took 600 seconds? You mentioned npgsql. Could you show us the code that's taking 600 seconds? This is likely to be the problem.

Comment: On the front side, my code example is like above @Schwern

Comment: Also, my min_log_duration_statement  is 200 ms. I catch the execution time in Postgres logs.

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY You have an `order by` which changes things, but even unindexed shouldn't take 10 minutes. Does it take 10 minutes to get to "Finished" or "End loop"? Can you post the actual Postgres logs?

Comment: [link](https://snipboard.io/eHIT6P.jpg) You can see my result also without `order by` sort.
The other quey is canceling statement due to statement timeout.

Comment: I think the problem is your one row of data is very big.

Answer (score 1):

If the query execution time as measured on the server, the problem must eiter be the network or the client that takes a long time to render the data.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I used but there is no change.

Comment: It could of yourse also be network related. Try discarding the result: `DO $$BEGIN PERFORM * from zamazin; END;$$;` and see if that is as slow.

Comment: Yes, it took 30 ms :) When I analyze my SQL query, it was the same with this result. But I want to visualize on my web page, but npgsql take this data 600 second. Is there any solution to take data fastly?

Comment: Then the only solution is to transfer less data to the client. Who wants to see 110 kB of data, unless it is an image? Perhaps you can extract the relevant data on the database server and transfer less.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not do that :) Because all of them are relevant data that includes user's information

Comment: Are you extracting data to a file? Then you need not render them, and it can be fast. I'm still lacking the imagination how one can visualize 110 kB all at once.